# How do we use ''how many''?

Tags: grammar

Let's say there is only one person who can lift 100kg in this world.

1. How many people do you know can lift 100kg in this world?
2. How many people do you know who can lift 100kg in this world?
3. Do you know how many people can lift 100kg in this world?
4. How many people can lift 100kg in this world?

Are these sentences all correct grammatically? Do I have to add 'who' to sentence Number 2?

Comment: Try to make questions about real problems that you face.  Since there are many people who can lift 100kg, this isn't a natural situation.  It is hard to discuss what is natural and grammatical in an unnatural context.

Comment: What are you asking? "Know" has multiple meanings. How many people I am acquainted with who can do that, how many people I know of who can do that (e.g. how many I can name), or are you asking if I know how many people in the world can do that regardless of whether I can name them or have ever met them? Are you asking a factual question, or trying to find out what I know (how many of the 50 states can you name?)?

Answer (score 3):

We say 'in *the* world' (we certainly don't know anything about weightlifters in any other world!) - but it's only necessary if we need to specify 'in the whole world'.

There are two kinds of questions here.

> Do you know how many people in the world can lift 100 kg?

asks for information about international weightlifting champions.

> How many people do you know who can lift 100 kg?

asks about people that you know personally.